# How to Auto-Trigger Jenkins based on GIT changes through web-hooks?

Tags: git, jenkins

GitHub is deprecating the integration services. Whats the easiest way to trigger the Jenkins through git web-hooks?

Comment: Why downvotes? Is a new member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your build job with below steps:

**1. Job URL:**

Get the Jenkins job URL (ex: https://buildtools.com/job/job-name)

**2. API TOKEN:**

Get your API token from Jenkins account. (**ex:fsdjlfs76dfsf6fsdfsf**)

**3. Create Job hook URL:**

Generate the build hook URL with this pattern:**http://jenkins_username:jenkins_API-TOKEN@job_url/build**

**NOTE:** if your job having build parameters use buildWithParameters instead of build.

Now, your job URL is ready to call. wherever u want to trigger you can just call.

**Example use cases:**

some sample use cases are listed below:

**Integrating with Github :**

- Login to your **GitHub** account.
- Click on your **Project** repository
- Click on your repository **settings**
- Click on Add Webhook paste your **Job hook URL** in payload URL input box select the event to call the job URL.
- click on Add **Webhook** check your Jenkins job by making some event in
  GitHub.

if any queries feel free comment below

Comment: I have a similar question pls lol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219220/how-to-trigger-greenhouses-web-hook

Answer (score 0):

[Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

[Command documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Once you configure/install the git-hooks into your environment, then the hook can be used to call your commands to do a build.